# How to make persistent AppBar and floating widget just below AppBar in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver, flutter-appbar, flutter-sliverappbar

I want to make my AppBar persistent (it should not float like tabbar) while I want to place a widget or say tabbar just below appbar which will float and be pinned to appbar just like spotify app of library page  see below for proper understanding

[image]

So far I have used slivers in flutter not able to achieve what I want,
Please check my code and correct me,

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(body: Test()),
    );
  }
}
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (context, value) {
            return [
              SliverAppBar(excludeHeaderSemantics: true,
                floating: true,
                           
                pinned: true,
                title: Text('This should be fixed not moving'),
                bottom: TabBar(
                  tabs: [
                    Tab( text: "Call"), // this shoudl be floating n pinned 
                    Tab( text: "Message"),// this should be floating n pinned
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Container(child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 100,
                  itemBuilder: (context,index){
                return Text("Item $index");
              })),
              Container(child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 100,
                  itemBuilder: (context,index){
                    return Text("Item $index");
                  })),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code below is working
as I wanted,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(body: Test()),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: NestedScrollView(
          floatHeaderSlivers: true,
          headerSliverBuilder: (context, value) {
            return [
              SliverAppBar(
                floating: true,
                pinned: true,
                
                title: Text('This should be fixed not moving'),
              ),
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate.fixed(
                  [
                    TabBar(
                      labelColor: Colors.blue,
                      tabs: [
                        Tab(text: "Call"),
                        Tab(text: "Message"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Container(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 100,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Text("Item $index");
                      })),
              Container(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 100,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Text("Item $index");
                      })),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SliverList` after the `SliverAppBar` and put your `TabBar` inside it.

here's what you are looking for.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(body: Test()),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (context, value) {
            return [
              SliverAppBar(
                excludeHeaderSemantics: true,
                floating: true,
                pinned: true,
                title: Text('This should be fixed not moving'),
              ),
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate.fixed(
                  [
                    TabBar(
                      labelColor: Colors.blue,
                      tabs: [
                        Tab(text: "Call"),
                        Tab(text: "Message"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Container(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 100,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Text("Item $index");
                      })),
              Container(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 100,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Text("Item $index");
                      })),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks it works partially but I want this tabbar to also appear back when I scroll upwards a bit also it appears only when scrolled fully above so any fix for this would help a lot.... the problem still is there is that I have to scroll all the way up to get my tabbar its a bit non user friendly UI

Comment: after adding `floatHeaderSlivers: true,` in NestedScrollView it works

Comment: i've tried that but didn't worked for me.

Comment: I have posted the proper working code below your answer and it works I figured out by just tweaking some changes in your code only and now it works, thanks a ton man!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `bottom` attribute for that on the `AppBar`.

Here is a link to an example on how to do it:

https://esflutter.dev/docs/catalog/samples/app-bar-bottom

Comment: At first I did that only but how to make the widget below appbar float i.e tabbar

Comment: Like it should not disappear, is that what you mean?

Comment: it should disappear when I scroll down and appear back when I move it upwards please check the gif image for clear understanding

Answer (score 0):

You could also restructure your UI to make it like this:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: <HERE_YOUR_APPBAR>,
  body: Column(
    children: [
      TabBar(), // here your tab bar,
      Expanded(
        child: TabBarView() // here your tabs
      )
    ]
  )
)
```

This way your TabBar will be anchored to the top while the Expanded will cover the rest of the **Column**'s real estate and fill your page.